# distribute Java classes and res folder separately

Tags: android, distribution

I have developed an android application, which uses image files and strings from the res folder. Is it possible for me to distribute the app in a manner that enables the users to modify the strings and images stored in the res folder, without accessing the code from the java classes.

Can I distribute these separately, so that a user can modify the value of the strings and replace the images (not add new or delete existing) and rebuild the apk, without being able to read the Java code?

Thanks.
Ani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to build a web interface where users can upload the images and strings they want into a form, you can generate the resources on the server, package it up and sign it, then give them back a download link.

The whole process could be automated as long as you have Java and  headless aapt installed on the server.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/index.html#detailed-build

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though this seems to be the best approach, I am afraid I cannot move forward with this at this point due to multiple issues related to time/ resources. Also, I need to this for just 1 user for an old app. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Is it possible for the user to 'unpack' the apk he has, modify the resources and then repackage all as an apk again? In this case, the user can make all the required changes, without using any of my resources.